# Response.Write() in WebService

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I want to return JSON data back to the client, in my web service method. One way is to create `SoapExtension` and use it as attribute on my web method, etc. Another way is to simply add `[ScriptService]` attribute to the web service, and let .NET framework return the result as `{"d": "something"}` JSON, back to the user (`d` here being something out of my control). However, I want to return something like:

```
{"message": "action was successful!"}
```

The simplest approach could be writing a web method like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void StopSite(int siteId)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    try
    {
        // Doing something here
        response.Write("{{\"message\": \"action was successful!\"}}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.StatusCode = 500;
        response.Write("{{\"message\": \"action failed!\"}}");
    }
}
```

This way, what I'll get at client is:

```
{ "message": "action was successful!"} { "d": null}
```

Which means that ASP.NET is appending its success result to my JSON result. If on the other hand I flush the response after writing the success message, (like `response.Flush();`), the exception happens that says:

> Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent.

So, what to do to just get my JSON result, without changing the approach?

Comment: Try setting response.BufferOutput = true;

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void ReturnExactValueFromWebMethod(string AuthCode)
{
    string r = "return my exact response without ASP.NET added junk";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(r);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: this lines helped me, but for me I have added these lines to make it works

Response.Flush();
Response.End();

Comment: ResponseEnd() cause “Thread was being aborted” 
This works for me! 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you return an object and then in your client you can call as `response.d`?

I don't know how you are calling your Web Service but I made an example making some assumptions:

I made this example using jquery ajax

```
function Test(a) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "TestRW.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    data: "{'id':" + a + "}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.d));

                    }
                });
            }
```

And your code could be like this (you need to allow the web service to be called from script first: '[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]'):

```
    [WebMethod]
    public object HelloWorld(int id)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("message","success");

        return dic;
    }
```

In this example I used dictionary but you could use any object with a field "message" for example.

I'm sorry if I missunderstood what you meant but I don't really understand why you want to do a 'response.write' thing.

Hope I've helped at least. :)